# MobileNet for object detection on *mobile*

Tags: android, tensorflow, detection, multibox, tensorflow-ssd

I am trying to use a MobileNet for object detection on Android. While fine-tuning the net worked fine, the resulting model cannot be used on Android.

It is incompatible (tensor names, shapes) with the Android object detection demo app using the TensorFlowMultiBoxDetector. Now I have a MobileNet that cannot be used on a mobile.

I have seen an Android object detection demo apparently using a MobileNetV1 at the CVPR2017, so it must be possible

Has anyone managed to do this? Any pointers how to modify the app?

Answer (score 0):

This has just been implemented in the android TensorFlow demo app. Kudos to Google! :-)